# Retrieving multiple data in to another list

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-lists

I have a SharePoint list "**Register**" that has a field "Asset"(title) and "Type"(choice).  The title is unique and the type will be multiples of the same.

| Asset | Type |
| --- | --- |
| 1212 | Blue |
| 1213 | Blue |
| 1214 | Red |

I have another list "**Spares**", that has a field of "Item"(title), "type"(choice) and "Asset"(string).

I want to be able select a "type" e.g. Blue and for all the asset numbers to automatically be shown in the column "Asset" based on list "Register"

| Item | Type | Asset |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Oil | Blue | 1212 1213 |
| Timber | Blue | 1212 1213 |
| Rubber | Red | 1214 |

How can I achieve this?